# loading a view via function in controller

Tags: php, templates, opencart

I am trying to get sizes chart as on of the tabs when product is selected in opencart. For this I have a model like below

```
class ModelCatalogSizes extends Model {     
    public function getSizes()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "sizes ORDER BY id");
        return $query->rows;
    }
}
```

I have view as a template for the same which is just a html table with values as input radio options.

In my product controller class, I have a function like below

```
public function sizes()
{
    $this->language->load('product/product');

    $this->load->model('catalog/sizes');

    $this->data['sizes'] = array();

    $results = $this->model_catalog_sizes->getSizes();

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $this->data['sizes'][] = array(
            'type'       => ucfirst($result['type']),
            'coat'       => $result['coat'],
            'chest'      => $result['chest'],
            'cverarm'    => $result['overarm'],
            'waist'      => $result['waist'],
            'hip'        => $result['hip'],
            'inseam'     => $result['inseam'],
            'neck'       => $result['neck'],
            'sleeve'     => $result['sleeve'],
            'height'     => $result['height'],
            'weightLb'   => $result['weightLb'],
            'weightKg'   => $result['weightKg'],
        );
    }

    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/sizes.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/sizes.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = 'default/template/product/sizes.tpl';
    }

    $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
}
```

Now I am trying to directly load this view via the index function in the product controller class by saying `$this->data['size'] = $this->sizes();`

When I echo my $size in my product view, nothing comes up. I'd presume the whole view built in the function above should show up. Am I wrong (probability 99%)? can someone help me with directly publishing the view via function?

Comment: Another solution for you paste the html of sizes.tpl in the if condition in product.tpl and donot `$this->response->setOutput($this->render());` just get data from sizes() in the index() function

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is add the route for that as a child of the `index()` method's children
Open `/catalog/controller/product/product.php` and find this code at the bottom of the `index()` method

```
$this->children = array(
    'common/column_left',
    'common/column_right',
    'common/content_top',
    'common/content_bottom',
    'common/footer',
    'common/header'
);
```

and add your route, which would be `'product/product/sizes'` for your `sizes()` method

```
$this->children = array(
    'common/column_left',
    'common/column_right',
    'common/content_top',
    'common/content_bottom',
    'common/footer',
    'common/header',
    'product/product/sizes'
);
```

And then in your template, you just need to use `<?php echo $sizes; ?>` wherever you want it to go

Comment: Yep yep, you have to call it as a child.